# Check if all values from array start with a string

Tags: ruby

I have an array of links:

```
urls =
[
  ["http://s3.amazonxaws.com/bb_images/uk/media_images/2/1-veXRiLqrxPbguaxFIcFbPA.png"],
  ["http://s3.amazonaws.com/bb_images/uk/media_images/2/1-veXRiLqrxPbguaxFIcFbPA.png"]
]
```

How can I return `true` if all links start with `"http://s3.amazonaws.com"`?

I tried:

```
if urls.any? { |url| url.include?('http://s3.amazonaws.com/') }
     #execute code
else
     #execute else code
end
```

But it does not return `true` or `false` in cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@sawa's code works. However, the following is a more efficient version.

```
compare_against = "http://s3.amazonaws.com"
urls.all?{|url_array| url_array[0].start_with?(compare_against)}
```

Comment: Good point about using a predefined string (and for avoiding an intermediate array). However, you can do that also by using the `freeze` optimization in string literals. `start_with?("http://s3.amazonaws.com".freeze)`.

Comment: You're right about freeze. In that case I wanted to avoid temporary array, because it requires 2 iterations (the first to create it, and the second to verify predicate).

Comment: Work's great, thank you, but the problem now is that `compare_against = ["http://s3.amazonaws.com", Rails.root] `, and I tried with each inside but every time is true

Comment: explain, what in your context `compare_against = ["http://s3.amazonaws.com", Rails.root]` means. Whether it's enough if string starts with any of compare_against, or it has to match all of them

Comment: If my string start with http://s3.amazonaws.com or RAILS.root (RAILS.root is current url domain) should return true.

Comment: `compare_against_array = ["http://s3.amazonaws.com", Rails.root]
urls.all?{|url_array| compare_against_array.any? { |ca|  url_array[0].start_with?(ca) } }
`

Answer (score 5):

```
urls.flatten.all?{|s| s.start_with?("http://s3.amazonaws.com")}
```